# Strip out a specific object value from json from rendering view with Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, json

I have an unordened list where each list item is given a data id, I need this ID value to update the view later, basically I cant remove the values from the json, is there a way to hide the value from the html without removing it from the json data? and console.log with a click? The objects are:
"level_0_id": 1,
"level_1_id": 1,
"level_2_id": 1,
"id": 1

Here is the code from the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/m4t8tszk/1/

Here's the Js:

```
function list(object) {
        var json="<ul class='dropdown'>";
        for(prop in object){
            var value = object[prop];
            switch (typeof(value)){
                case "object":
                        var token = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,16);

                        json += "<li><div id='"+ token +"' class='collapse'>"+list(value)+"</div></li>";
                        break;
                        default:

                        json += "<li>"+value+"</li>";
                    }
                }
                return json+"</ul>";
            }

        $(document).ready(function() {

            console.log(data);
            $('#sidebar').html(list(data));
        });
```

Comment: How will the `li` be selected , clicked if hidden , not displayed ?

Comment: This will be when the user click .

Comment: See post below. `click` `event` assigned to parent container `#output`. Is expected result the `li` that are `hidden` , `display:none` , be clicked ?

Comment: Basically you click "li" element  like {"name": "Jane Doe","id": 789} output ID, if parent like "level_2_id": 2789" output children id's and so on, does't make sense for you?

Comment: Hide `li` having text "3333" ,  `click` element having text "John Doe", log `3333` at `console` ?

Comment: "li" with ID like "level_0_id": 1, should be hidden, clicking on the previous parent "li"item in this case ""level_0_name": "Americas"," will output  hidden children ids and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var filter = ["12345", "2451", "3333"];
    var result = $(list(data)).map(function(i, el) {
        var res = $("li", el).filter(function(idx, elem) {
          return $.inArray(elem.textContent, filter) !== -1
        }).fadeTo(0,0, function() {

          var el = this;
          $(":contains(Americas)")
          .on("click", function() {
            console.log(el.textContent)
          })
        })

        return el
    })
    $("#output").html(result);   
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m4t8tszk/4/

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a specific way of organizing information. So calling your html string "json" isn't really accurate. I'd change it to "listView" or something.

You can always use JQuery. Just add a class (like hide) to whatever you want to do stuff to.

```
$(".hide").click(function(event) { 
  var clickedThing = event.currentTarget // Also could use the keyword "this"
  var clickedThing.hide();
});
```

I recomend having a hidden and a visible class. If you click one, have JQuery switch it to the other.

Comment: I will rename "json" to listView as recommend, @MDrewT

Comment: you can also do things like creating a temporary json object that you CAN delete stuff out of. Or use JQuery to edit the value of the list item in the html.

Comment: I really like the option of editing the value of the item, will try that.

Comment: ok, just be careful that you do a deep copy otherwise you could edit the original by mistake

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object